# The domain of your function doesn't match that of the correct answer

Tags: integration

After working through this problem, webwork gives me "The domain of your function doesn't match that of the correct answer".  Usually this happens if you have a log function that needs absolute value bars or are missing a +C, but that doesn't apply here so I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious in the question?

$$\int\frac{\sec^2(8t)\tan^2(8t)}{\sqrt{16-\tan^2(8t)}}dt
$$

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS63D.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that inside the $\tan$ you have $8t/4$ and the $4$ should be on the outside of the parens.  (Otherwise you'd write $\tan 2t$, eh?_)

Comment: Perfect!  That's totally correct, thanks!